# Too many floats within div

Tags: html, css, break

So I'm trying to run 3 floats within a div and I run into this problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/sPUjQ/101/`click me`

Whenever I run two floats the background color stays but when I attempt 3 floats then it's gone!

Can someone tell me what's happening and why it's doing this? I don't encounter this when doing inline-blocks, just float: left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When floating child divs, the parent collapses because they're removed from the normal document flow. Add `overflow:auto` on the parent to restore the behavior you're after:

```
.contain {
    display: block;
    background: blue;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/sPUjQ/102/)**

Comment: or just change your floats to display: inline-block

Comment: That did the trick!!!. Do you happen to have a link to explain further  details about this type of behavior? It doesn't make any sense as to why this could happen.

Comment: Well, for the in-depth look at floats, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float and http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to retain the blue background in both `.contains`? If yes then you will have to remove `float: left` to `children of .contains` and add `display: inline`.

See my revise [code](http://jsfiddle.net/sPUjQ/104/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I knew how to do it for inline, just confused since float and inline visually work the same but behave differently. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following example,
Float each separately,

```
.contain{width: 100%; background: blue; margin: 0 auto;}
.one, .four{float: left; background: red;}
.two, .five{float: left; background: orange;}
.three, .six{float: left; background: yellow;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ShamalSandeep/km8twgvf/1/

Comment: I was trying to retain the blue. trying to understand why it vanishes.

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the floats at the end of the container div, otherwise it will collapse.

```
.clear{
clear:both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sPUjQ/105/

You can read more in detail about floats and their quirks here > http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: I was trying to make them go side-by-side.